# Lookupset function returning #Error

Tags: reporting-services

The following function displays the error #Error:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Review_Last_Modified_On_Date.Value,"UTReviews") (LookupSet(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Review_Last_Modified_On_Date.Value,"UTReviews").Length -1)
```

Comment: The second lookup set - is that _supposed_ to be a separate line?

Also, what if it is null - your .Length will return an error.

Comment: That is the problem, the array element is 0 so it's returning the #error.  The second lookup set is providing me with the last element in the array.

Comment: This is what someone wrote and how I got my code from another site: Well, the example in the post shows how to get a count of the elements:

=LookupSet(Fields!StateProvinceCode.Value,Fields!StateProvinceCode.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value,”Dataset2″).Length

 So to get the last element, you would use this expression.

=LookupSet(Fields!StateProvinceCode.Value,Fields!StateProvinceCode.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value,”Dataset2″)(LookupSet(Fields!StateProvinceCode.Value,Fields!StateProvinceCode.Value, Fields!CustomerID.Value,”Dataset2″).Length -1)

Comment: Index Array Elements Max Array Values
345732 0                            #Error
322911 0                            #Error
707460 2                           7/19/2016 2:13:02 PM
643614 0                            #Error
673923 1                           7/19/2016 2:20:48 PM

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish with this expression. You have two statements without any operator between them. What is the desired outcome?

Comment: The second statement provides with the Max value.  Example if I have two dates 7/1/2016 and 7/4/2016, the statement returns 7/4/2016 into the Lookupset field.  But if the record does not contain any dates I get #error message.  I'm trying to figure out a way to bypass blank rows